# Generalization of Cauchy-Davenport inequality to $\mathbb Z_p^d$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory

Is there some generalization of Cauchy-Davenport inequality to the group $\mathbb Z_p^d$? ($p$ prime number, $d \ge 3$)

For example, Kneser Theorem says that if $G$ is any abelian group and $\varnothing \neq A,B \subset G$ then there exists a subgroup $H < G$ such that $|A+B| \ge |A+H| + |B+H| - |H|$. In fact, $H = stab(A+B)$ works.

In some way, is it true that if $G = \mathbb Z_p^d$ and at least one of the disjunct subsets $A,B$ is affine basis of $\mathbb Z_p^d$ then I can take $H$ with only one element?

I need an inequality similar to the Cauchy-Davenport one.

Thank you!